# CMake Qt5 can't generate header file for ui file AUTOUIC

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

I can't generate the header for my ui files with cmake 3.5.2 and Qt 5.9.

My CMakeFileLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project( fc_app )
message( STATUS "Configuring project")


set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

message( STATUS "search OpenCV")
find_package(
    OpenCV
    3.2.0
    REQUIRED
)

message( STATUS "search Qt")
find_package(
    Qt5
    5.5.1
    REQUIRED
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        Multimedia
)

message( STATUS "search Boost")
find_package(
    Boost
    1.58.0
    REQUIRED
)


file( GLOB_RECURSE source_files src/* )
file( GLOB_RECURSE header_files include/* )
file( GLOB_RECURSE ui_files ui/* )
file( GLOB_RECURSE res_files res/* )

add_executable(
    fc_app
    ${source_files}
    ${header_files}
    ${ui_files}
)

target_link_libraries(
    fc_app
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Multimedia
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

I get the following error (in make) when I run `cmake .. & make` in the root/build/ directory. The ui file is a simple QMainWindow with 2 buttons in it, so I don't unterstand why the generation of ui_mainwindow.h failed. I tried to remake the ui file with an other version of Qt5 Designer too.

```
File '/blablablabla/mainwindow.ui' is not valid
AUTOUIC: error: process for ui_mainwindow.h needed by
 "/blablablabla/mainwindow.cpp"
failed:
File '/blablablabla/mainwindow.ui' is not valid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a quirk with CMake and QT for AUTOUIC. It is [claimed](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html) that CMake will automatically scan files for ui file includes though it does not work if the ui include is on the **first line** of the source file.

So following setup:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project("proj")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "$ENV{QTDIR}")
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR "YES")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC "YES")
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC "YES")

add_executable("proj" MACOSX_BUNDLE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries("proj" Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets)
```

`form.ui`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Will fail to compile with `main.cpp` having:

```
1. #include "ui_form.h"
2.
3. int main() {
4. }
```

> ```
> $ cmake --build .
> Scanning dependencies of target proj_automoc
> [ 25%] Automatic moc and uic for target proj
> Generating moc compilation proj_automoc.cpp
> [ 25%] Built target proj_automoc
> Scanning dependencies of target proj
> [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/proj.dir/main.cpp.o
> main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'ui_form.h' file not found
> #include "ui_form.h"
>          ^
> 1 error generated.
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/proj.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/proj.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

However if your ui include is not on the first line:

```
1. 
2. #include "ui_form.h"
3. int main() {
4. }
```

> ```
> $ cmake --build .
> [ 25%] Automatic moc and uic for target proj
> Generating ui header ui_form.h
> [ 25%] Built target proj_automoc
> Scanning dependencies of target proj
> [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/proj.dir/main.cpp.o
> [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/proj.dir/proj_automoc.cpp.o
> [100%] Linking CXX executable proj.app/Contents/MacOS/proj
> [100%] Built target proj
> ```

---

UPD.
[This regular expression](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.10.2/Source/cmQtAutoGenerators.cxx#L156-157) used to scan for include is the culprit:

```
this->UicRegExpInclude.compile("[\n][ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]+"
                               "[\"<](([^ \">]+/)?ui_[^ \">/]+\\.h)[\">]");
```

It is still there in latest release 3.10.2 but already fixed in [3.11](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.11.0/Source/cmQtAutoGeneratorMocUic.cxx#L1135-1136):

```
Uic_.RegExpInclude.compile("(^|\n)[ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]+"
                           "[\"<](([^ \">]+/)?ui_[^ \">/]+\\.h)[\">]");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this issue is for that particular version of CMake, but a had the same problem and released that if your `ui` file has uppercases, for example `MuyWidget.ui`, then you have that error with CMake. The solution for me was to name the `ui` files with lowercase as `mywidget.ui` instead of `MyWidget.ui`.

Comment: Note: I'm using linux

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in my source where I was included the generated ui file I was using Ui_*.h rather than **u**i_*.h

It's case sensitive when parsing the source files to determine the ui files to autouic.